# Dell xps microphone distortion

Tags: sound, microphone, xps, soundcard

I installed ubuntu on a dell xps laptop thinking everything would be compatible. It seemed to work fine after installation, except for the sound, and on that point, there are a number of problems.

Most importantly: microphone captures sound with such extreme distortion that no conversation is possible in webchat. Same distortion on video capture.

There are various other problems as well, but most important for the moment is finding some way to use a microphone without screeching distortion (even just to record a test-video in cheese, for example).

Specs:

```
Dell XPS 13 9305
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
$ uname -srm
Linux 5.13.0-28-generic x86_64

$cat /proc/asound/card0/codec\*  | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC3271
Codec: Intel Tigerlake HDMI
```

It sounds similar to [this problem](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-9380-2019-running-factory-installed-Ubuntu-cracking-and/td-p/7855271) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235198/white-noise-in-microphone-with-ubuntu-20-04).

If anybody has any ideas how to get the microphone working, I'd much appreciate any help you can offer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution worked for me:

Install qasmixer from terminal:

`sudo apt-get install qasmixer`

then run $qasmixer

View -> Show Device Selection -> hw: Card

And turn "Internal Mic Boost" all the way down. It might be helpful to record a video in Cheese while adjusting these values and listen to the change it makes to the sound in real time.